# RBAC not working as expected when trying to lock namespace

Tags: kubernetes, roles, kubectl, rbac

I'm trying to lock down a namespace in kubernetes using **RBAC** so I followed this [tutorial](https://blog.viktorpetersson.com/2018/06/15/kubernetes-rbac.html).
I'm working on a **baremetal cluster** (no minikube, **no cloud provider**) and installed kubernetes using Ansible.

I created the folowing **namespace :**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: lockdown
```

**Service account :**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa-lockdown
  namespace: lockdown
```

**Role :**

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: lockdown
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: [""]
  verbs: [""]
```

**RoleBinding :**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: rb-lockdown
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: sa-lockdown
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: lockdown
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

And finally I tested the authorization using the next command

```
kubectl auth can-i get pods --namespace lockdown --as system:serviceaccount:lockdown:sa-lockdown
```

This **SHOULD** be returning "No" but I got "Yes" :-(

What am I doing wrong ?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what was the problem.

The *role* and *rolebinding* **must** be created inside the targeted namespace.

I changed the following role and rolebinding types by specifying the namespace inside the yaml directly.

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: lockdown
  namespace: lockdown
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - watch
  - list
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: rb-lockdown
  namespace: lockdown
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: sa-lockdown
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: lockdown
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

In this example I gave permission to the user **sa-lockdown** to ***get*, *watch* and *list*** the **pods** in the namespace **lockdown**.

---

Now if I ask to get the pods : `kubectl auth can-i get pods --namespace lockdown --as system:serviceaccount:lockdown:sa-lockdown` it will return **yes**.

On the contrary if ask to get the deployments : `kubectl auth can-i get deployments --namespace lockdown --as system:serviceaccount:lockdown:sa-lockdown` it will return **no**.

---

You can also leave the files like they were in the question and simply create them using `kubectl create -f <file> -n lockdown`.

Answer (score 1):

A couple possibilities:

1. are you running the "can-i" check against the secured port or unsecured port (add --v=6 to see). Requests made against the unsecured (non-https) port are always authorized.
2. RBAC is additive, so if there is an existing clusterrolebinding or rolebinding granting "get pods" permissions to that service account (or one of the groups system:serviceaccounts:lockdown, system:serviceaccounts, or system:authenticated), then that service account will have that permission. You cannot "ungrant" permissions by binding more restrictive roles

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Unfortunatly my cluster died :-(   -  I'll need more time to test this solution !